# I need to edit a text file with a non-constant structure. Trying to use pandas, is this the best tool for the job?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change a textfile but this will have to be done a lot so I thought I would use the chance to learn how to use python to edit text files.

The text file I have looks something like this:

```
title1
title2
...
title5
var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
var1.1 var2.1 var3.1 var4.1 var5.1
```

So on and so forth. The titles can extend to be anywhere from 5 to 18 and the number of titles = the number of columns for the rows with the variables.

The variable rows can get into the hundreds of thousands.

I need to basically add a single title (constant) and then onto every row I need to add an extra column that is dependent on a number somewhere in var1 (a string) of that row.

Is pandas the correct thing to be using here? Currently when I just import it using read_table it doesn't like the addition of delimiter information I assume because the initial rows are just a single thing.

All advice would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: If the text file is not ridiculously large I would strongly recommend just doing pure python. Instead of learning two things you can just learn one. Barring that, clean the file first so that it is in a nice format, then use pandas if it is necessary. I would note that it is very hard to do this sort of stuff if the file is actually not consistent (random).

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with pure Python. In this example I firstly parse the string (can be read from file) to Python structures, make the desired operation (add a single title, add column to row based on first item on that row), and write the values back:

```
data = """
title1
title2
title3
title4
title5
var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
var1.1 var2.1 var3.1 var4.1 var5.1
"""

import re


# parse string to Python structures:
titles = re.findall(r'^(\w+)$', data, flags=re.M)
rows = []
for row in re.finditer(r'^.*? .*?$', data, flags=re.M):
    rows.append([])
    for values in re.finditer(r'[\w\.]+', row[0]):
        rows[-1].append(values[0])

# add title:
titles.append('NEWTITLE')

# add value to all rows (some example operation with column 0):
for row in rows:
    row.append('NEW' + row[0])

# print values back to old form:
for title in titles:
    print(title)
for row in rows:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

Outputs:

```
title1
title2
title3
title4
title5
NEWTITLE
var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 NEWvar1
var1.1 var2.1 var3.1 var4.1 var5.1 NEWvar1.1
```

Comment: Thank you, Having issues with it recognising the rows as strings. Perhaps I am importing the file incorrectly. Currently I am running it as data = open(TextFileEditing, "w"). If I try read and append mode it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Jt246 you open open the file with `f = open('my_data.txt', 'r')` and read it with `f.read()`

Comment: Sorry I was being silly. Thank you. I know get the error
for values in re.finditer(r'[\w\.]+', row[0]):
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

But I think you have pointed me in the right direction I just need to familiarise myself with the re commands. Thank you.